# Undefined variables in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a controller called `Job_search` and 
in my Job_search.php I declare some variables:

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Job_search extends CI_Controller {

public $keyword='Driver';
public $location='KL__ Kerala KT__ Kottayam Vaikom';
public $district='78';
public $listing_type = 'Job';
public $listings_per_page = '10';
public $page='1';

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Job_search_model');
  }
public function index() {
$result=$this->Job_search_model->get_job_search_result($keyword,$location,$district,$listing_type,$listings_per_page,$page);
  }
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Undefined variable: keyword

Undefined variable: location

Undefined variable: district

Undefined variable: listing_type

Undefined variable: listings_per_page

Undefined variable: page
```

Comment: Use `$this->keyword`, `$this->location`... etc and check

Answer (score 2):

```
public function index()
{
  $result=
  $this->Job_search_model->get_job_search_result(
    $this->keyword,
    $this->location,
    $this->district,
    $this->listing_type,
    $this->listings_per_page,
    $this->page);
}
```

Try this, you need `$this->` infront, you are calling a variable from within the class so `$this->test` is how to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using the `this` keyword anywhere in the class:

```
$this->varibale_name;
```